# Raising events from a mock/stub using Rhino Mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, events, rhino-mocks

How can I raise an event from a mock/stub using Rhino Mocks?

I've found some answers to this question on the web, but they all seem to use the Record/Replay-syntax, but I'm using the Arrange/Act/Assert syntax.

Any suggestions?

A little example...

Let's say I'm using the MVVM pattern and have this model class:

```
public class MyModel
{
    private int _myValue;

    public event EventHandler ValueChanged;

    public void SetValue(int newValue)
    {
        _myValue = newValue;
        if (ValueChanged != null)
        {
            ValueChanged(this, null);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the class has an integer value and a method that sets it. When the value is set, a `ValueChanged` event is raised.

This model class is used by a viewmodel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    private MyModel _myModel;

    public MyViewModel(MyModel myModel)
    {
        _myModel = myModel;
        _myModel.ValueChanged += ValueChangedHandler;
    }

    private void ValueChangedHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyString = "Value has changed";
    }

    public string MyString { get; set; }
}
```

This viewmodel listen to the `ValueChanged` event on the model and updates when it is raised.

Now I want to test that the viewmodel is updated when the model  raises the event.

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyViewModel_ModelRaisesValueChangedEvent_MyStringIsUpdated()
{
    //Arrange.
    var modelStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<MyModel>();
    MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel(modelStub);

    //Act
    -HERE I WANT TO RAISE THE VALUE CHANGED EVENT FROM modelStub.

    //Assert.
    Assert.AreEqual("Value has changed", viewModel.MyString);
}
```

Note that this is just an example and not my actual code (which is more complex). I hope you can disregard any typos and other small mistakes.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyViewModel_ModelRaisesValueChangedEvent_MyStringIsUpdated()
{
    //Arrange.
    var modelStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IModel>();
    MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel(modelStub);

    //Act
    modelStub.Raise(
       x => x.ValueChanged += null,
       modelStub, // sender
       EventArgs.Empty);

    //Assert.
    Assert.AreEqual("Value has changed", viewModel.MyString);
}
```

**Edit:** The error you are encountering can probably be solved by changing the stub type to an interface `IModel`  (that's how my own tests work). I have changed it in example above, but you will also have to change the `MyViewModel` constructor declaration to take the interface type.

Adding the `virtual` keyword to the event declaration may also work.